# Start new Activity "behind" current activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a splash screen activity `SpalshScreenActivity.java` that shows for few seconds.

Meanwhile, it starts another Activity `HomeActivity.java`, which does some processing and needs few seconds to load.

```
   //Start a new activity in the BG
   Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
   //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   this.startActivity(i);

   //Remove this activity after few seconds so the HomeActivity shows in the FG
   Timer timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           finish();
       }
   }, 2000);
```

How can I start the HomeActivity without bringing it to the front?

Comment: Shouldn't you do your processing on Splash activity and once its done, load your `HomeActivity`? If needed pass data to this activity.

Comment: Or you have a controller class, let's call it, AppManager, that will do processing for you? Once you start the SplashActivity, AppManager start processing, and after everything is ready, then you can start the HomeActivity. That way you can keep the processed data in the AppManager class(if static) or instance.

Comment: yes if there's no satisfactory answer to this question I will switch to that solution.. I'm trying to avoid making a lot of modification

Comment: **"which does some processing"** : What exactly does that mean? How does it do "some processing"? What is it doing?

Comment: waiting for the sqllitedb to be filled from a bg service so it can refresh the listview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one activity can be running at any one time. It was because of this limitation that fragments were introduced to support two 'views' on a tablet. You generally don't want an entire activity if all its doing is showing a progress bar/spinner.

If all that the splash screen is doing is showing a spinner then you should really make it part of the layout in the MainActivity. Make the MainActivity layout a RelativeLayout and then spinner match parent with a background.

When the MainActivity is done loading you can set visibility to gone. If you want you can even add an animation so that the splash screen flows of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the logic of the given activity in a fragment 
and swap the splash screen fragment with the loaded fragment when its done loading.

All this happens in the same activity

Answer (score 0):

Start `SpalshScreenActivity.java` on onCreate of `HomeActivity.java` before `setContentView` bug don't finish one. At this time  `HomeActivity.java` loads data and doesn't visible. After few seconds only finish splash